# linue kernel driver, dereference pointer and printk

Tags: linux, kernel, driver

this is a testing device driver code.
I have kernel space data which is dptr->data.
Afte I copyt it to user. I would like to printk it.

But my printk seems prints out address.

```
if (copy_to_user(buf, dptr->data[s_pos] + q_pos, count)) {

for(i=0;i<count;i++){
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "data:%p\n ",(dptr->data[s_pos]+q_pos+i));
}
```

If I change it to

```
printk(KERN_NOTICE "data:%p\n ",(void*)*(dptr->data[s_pos]+q_pos+i));
```

compile failed.
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*p` is a format specifier for a pointer, ie, an address.

If you want to print data, you will need an appropriate format specifier for the type of data you want to print - for example `%x` though this depends on the data type.

To get at the data you will have to dereference a pointer.  You are trying to cast your pointer to a (void *) and de-reference that, but void pointers by definition canot be de-referenced.  So you'll need to cast to an appropriate data type.

For example:

```
printk(KERN_NOTICE "data:%x\n ",
       *((u8*)(dptr->data[s_pos]+q_pos+i)); //print as byte

printk(KERN_NOTICE "data:%x\n ",
       *((u32*)(dptr->data[s_pos]+q_pos+i)); //print as 32-bit word
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [printk-formats.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt) kernel documentation:

```
If variable is of Type,             use printk format specifier:
---------------------------------------------------------
            int                     %d or %x
            unsigned int            %u or %x
            long                    %ld or %lx
            unsigned long           %lu or %lx
            long long               %lld or %llx
            unsigned long long      %llu or %llx
            size_t                  %zu or %zx
            ssize_t                 %zd or %zx

Raw pointer value SHOULD be printed with %p.
```